# How can I remove and append element li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html code like this :

```
<ul class="list">
    <li id="thumb-view-1">view 1</li>
    <li id="thumb-view-2">view 2</li>
    <li id="thumb-upload-3">upload 3</li>
    <li id="thumb-view-4">view 4</li>
    <li id="thumb-view-5">view 5</li>
</ul>
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

My javascript code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#test').on("click", function(e){
        var a = 3;
        for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            if(i == a) {
                $('#thumb-upload-'+i).remove();
                var res = '<li id="thumb-view-'+i+'">view '+i+'</li>';
                $('#thumb-view-'+(i-1)).after(res);
            }

        }
    });
</script>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/eb114sak/

It works

But my case is dynamic. var a has value between 1 - 5. So var a can have value 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5

While ul tag has 5 li tag. And 5 li tag can have different id type

So in addition to the tag li above, I give an example of another form

Like this :

```
<ul class="list">
    <li id="thumb-upload-1">upload 1</li>
    <li id="thumb-view-2">view 2</li>
    <li id="thumb-view-3">view 3</li>
    <li id="thumb-view-4">view 4</li>
    <li id="thumb-view-5">view 5</li>
</ul>
```

etc

If like that, the result still wrong

It seems it should call the li element based on `a`

So if a = 3 then the third li tag is deleted and append

But, I'm still confused

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of remove / append, try replaceWith:

```
$('#test').on("click", function(e){
    var a = 3;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        if(i == a) {
            var res = '<li id="thumb-view-'+i+'">view '+i+'</li>';
            $('#thumb-upload-'+i).replaceWith(res);             
        }           
    }
});
```

This will only replace matching `#thumb-upload-` elements, so it will handle your dynamic cases.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to use `replaceWith` and `index` as

```
var index = $( "ul.list" ).index( $("li[id^='thumb-upload']") );
```

This will get the index of li whose class starts with `thumb-upload` within your unordered list

```
$("li[id^='thumb-upload']").replaceWith('<li id="thumb-view-'+index +'">view '+index +'</li>';)
```

And the above statement will replace that list item with your custom HTML

Another simple solution is to just change the ID as I don't see other changes as

```
$("li[id^='thumb-upload']").attr('id', $("li[id^='thumb-upload']").attr('id').replace('upload','view'));
```